# Why I can't see my forms/templates in the Sitecore Forms application?

Tags: sitecore-forms

I have created some forms and templates in the [Sitecore Forms application](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/sitecore_forms), but I can't see them being listed in the grid of the Sitecore Forms main page.

It only displays the message "There are no forms to display.". I've tried to switch to "All forms", "My forms", and "All templates", but all the options give me the same message.

[image]

The forms are visible in the Content Tree, though:

[image]

The Sitecore logs don't say much

[image]

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: You need to rebuild your index(es) - had this as well, and rebuilding the master index fixed it each time.

Comment: I had the same issue when solr had issue with creating cores. Could you open a solr admin paned and see if there are any errors in the Log?

Comment: Yeah. I figured it out. I noticed some errors on Solr and then I rebuilt my index(es). While I was posting the answer, you've just added this comment! Thanks! =)

Comment: Has rebuilding helped with errors in log?

Comment: @artsem-prashkovich, I don't get those errors anymore. I am getting some warnings, though.  `16/11/2017, 15:57:37 WARN false LukeRequestHandler Error getting file length for [segments_1]`.

Comment: I also has warnings but it doesn't affect to work capacity =)

Comment: After following above all steps i have face no luck to relove. I found better and simple solution as below- https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/19013/sitecore-forms-are-not-appearing-in-sitecore-forms-interface/28895#28895

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Basically, I had to rebuild my index(es). I noticed some errors logged on the Solr Admin page, but after rebuilding all indexes, I can see my forms and templates:

[image]

[image]

Comment: that's the reason why I recommend you solr 6.6.2  . on 6.6.1 I have same errors like you on solr logs

Comment: @SitecoreClimber. I had the same problem on Solr 6.6.2 as well. Rebuilding the Mater DB Index was the solution for me as well.

Comment: one time this solution was work but not 2nd time

Answer (score 2):

I also followed all mentioned steps but still I was unable to see the forms. In Chrome developer tools I noticed I got a 403 Forbidden when requesting

```
/sitecore/api/ssc/forms/formdesign/formdesign/languages?sc_formmode=edit&_=1549524616558
```

Then I started to look further on 403 reponses on SC API requests. Eventually this led me to a suggestion to clear all my browser cookies. This solved the issue for me.

Comment: I think It would be better if you create a new question and describe you issue and steps that you've done to solve. It will be much more effective than to put a question as an answer to another question.

Comment: rebuild index was 1st time 
2nd time your solution work thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore Forms were missing in the Forms Designer view after upgrading the application to `version 10.2`. I created a new form and I am able to see it but the previous ones were not there. To fix the same I tried the below steps:

1. Cleared browser cache
2. Cleared Sitecore cache `/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx`
3. Incognito/private mode to see if able to see the Forms
4. Rebuilt Forms folder from the `Developer menu` (It solved my issue and happy to see the Forms in Forms Designer)
   [image]
5. If `step 4` does not help you then Rebuilt Sitecore Master Index

Refer blog post for more details: [Sitecore Forms are Missing in the Forms Designer](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2022/06/sitecore-forms-are-missing-in-forms-designer.html)

Answer (score 1):

I followed the below blog to fix my issue which as clear troubleshooting steps.

https://sitecoresandbox.com/2018/03/09/there-are-no-forms-to-display-in-sitecore-9-forms-designer/

1. I tried re-build index (didn't work)
2. Rename forms from content editor (worked)

Then I was able to see disappeared in forms application.